# how to create this as an index view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT u.Id FROM Users u WHERE FREETEXT((FirstName,Lastname,MiddleName),'') 
UNION  
SELECT c.AId FROM Certification c WHERE FREETEXT(*,'') 
UNION  
SELECT ad.AId FROM ApplicantDetails ad WHERE FREETEXT(*,'') 
UNION  
SELECT eb.AId FROM EducationalBackground eb WHERE FREETEXT(*,'') 
UNION  
SELECT ed.AId FROM EmploymentDetails ed WHERE FREETEXT(*,'') 
UNION  
SELECT e.AId FROM Expertise e WHERE FREETEXT(*,'') 
UNION  
SELECT ge.AId FROM GeographicalExperience ge WHERE FREETEXT(*,'') 
UNION  
SELECT pd.AId FROM ProjectDetails pd WHERE FREETEXT(*,'') 
UNION  
SELECT r.AId FROM [References] r WHERE FREETEXT(*,'') 
UNION  
SELECT t.AId FROM Training t WHERE FREETEXT(*,'')
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have union in an indexed view or freetext, there are more limitations, here is a partial list

- An expression on a column used in the GROUP BY clause, or an expression on the results of an aggregate.
- A derived table.
- A common table expression (CTE).
- Rowset functions.
- **UNION**, EXCEPT or INTERSECT operators.
- The full-text predicates CONTAINS or **FREETEXT**.
- Subqueries.
- Outer or self joins.
- TOP clause.
- ORDER BY clause.
- DISTINCT keyword.

See here for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx

One way to get around this is to use a stored procedure instead

Comment: ok, so do you any other options to revised the query above?The query is used to search a keywords in different tables.

Comment: actually i have a SP for keyword search, this portion is part of the keyword search, so all I need now is to recreate a query for search instead of the above or else any other solution contributed by anyone else...

Answer (score 1):

You can't have unions in an indexed view. You may be able to re-phrase the query as a series of joins though. Also, you can't use FREETEXT with the indexed views. You may be able to get the same effect by naming the columns and using LIKE.

The alternative to using an indexed view is to construct a normal table and use triggers on each of the source tables to keep it updated.

Comment: actually I used LIKE lately but I am not contented with the results if you search more than a million records I must say LIKE is not recommended to use instead, that is why I switch to full text search

Comment: If the view was indexed with LIKE, the cost would be spent when rows are inserted or deleted. There's really no point to use full text search indexing to support ANOTHER index in the indexed view.